# Trouble with normal maps

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Hello to everyone I have a small problem.
I used Smart UV unwrap to create UV map for a cave room and it work well when painting it in blender and using just diffuse map, but problem starts when I creating Normal map in CrazyBump and apply it to mesh in Unity all faces just becope bulging.
Can some one please help, maybe I should use another program to create a normal maps from complicated textures?
Here some pics that better describe my problem:
[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EvuMBz-PT6d25JR2hKeEhIcWM/view?usp=sharing

Here some pic with my UvMap

Comment: I assume the model looks totally normal when the normal map is removed?

Comment: @JohnsonMartin Yes it is.